# Delete image on clicking "X" mark on right top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to delete a image by clicking "X" mark on right top of image, I followed this fidddle for CSS http://jsfiddle.net/yHNEv/.

**HTML code:**

```
 <div class="img-wrap">
  <span  ng-click="deleteLocalfile()" class="close">&times;</span>
  <a id="div2" href><img ng-src="{{imagepreviewUrl}}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
 $scope.deleteLocalfile = function(){

  var result = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);

  wrappedResult.remove();

}
```

The above Code deleteting the "X"  mark on clicking it, not the Image, however after clicking "X" i am getting an event over here.

**The 2nd Approach:**

```
 <div class="img-wrap">
  <span   class="close">&times;</span>
  <a  ng-click="deleteLocalfile()" id="div2" href><img ng-src="{{imagepreviewUrl}}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

2nd Approach Controller Code

```
$scope.deleteLocalfile = function(){
var result = document.getElementsById("div2");
 var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
 wrappedResult.remove();
}
```

Here I am not getting event on clicking "X" mark, getting an event on image click deleting only the Image retaining "X" mark.

Comment: FYI stackoverflow have it's own Fiddle system ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially Sasikumar's answer rewritten to not use jQuery.

```js
var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrap .close')

for (var i = 0, l = closeBtns.length; i < l; i++) {
  closeBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var imgWrap = this.parentElement;
    imgWrap.parentElement.removeChild(imgWrap);
  });
}
```

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px red solid;
  font-size: 0;
}
.img-wrap .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 2px 2px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-wrap:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/2282/2282459-fisheye-tank.jpg" width="200" data-id="123">
</div>

<div class="img-wrap">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/38a/kendo-armor-3-1431999.jpg" width="100" data-id="103">
</div>
```

JSFiddle, if that's preferred: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/0xugckje/

Comment: thanks for your answer, its  working!!!. I want to  upload another image  after deleting the present one, i have a button next to deleted image, but its not working asking for page refresh, as it deleting the DIV , how do I upload another image without refreshing the page??,

Comment: What do you mean by "asking for page refresh?"

Comment: after page refresh only i am able to upload to another image, as it is deleting that DIV.

Comment: Are you able to provide a working example? From what I understand, you _are_ able to upload an image, but if you delete an image first, you have to reload before you can upload another? I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$('.img-wrap .close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.img-wrap').remove();
});
```

```css
.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px red solid;
    font-size: 0;
}
.img-wrap .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 2px 2px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .2;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-wrap:hover .close {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-wrap">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/2282/2282459-fisheye-tank.jpg" width="200" data-id="123">
</div>

<div class="img-wrap">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/38a/kendo-armor-3-1431999.jpg" width="100" data-id="103">
</div>
```

jsfiddle demo  http://jsfiddle.net/yHNEv/356/

Comment: This works, but the question doesn't mention JQuery, so ideally answers shouldn't use it.

Comment: I submitted an answer that doesn't rely on jQuery; however, the OP does present a source that uses it as a main point of reference, so I would imagine there's no issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change this css:

```
.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px red solid;
    font-size: 0;
}

.img-wrap .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```